# 13.04 - I Changed Resolution,, now Unity is Missing

Tags: unity, 13.04

I changed the resolution on one of my 13.04 dual monitors, and now I lost Unity, and icons.  Is there any trick to getting it back?

I am sort of stuck. I had the same problem earlier, and ended up having to re-install.  I really want to avoid re-installing again.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried changing the resolution back? Try hitting `Win` key and typing `Display` + enter.

Answer (score 0):

Use Ctrl+Alt+F4 to get a console window. Run `unity` from the prompt.
Ctrl+Alt+F7 should take you back to your Unity desktop with icons and menus.

Comment: Before you can run Unity you'll have to set your DISPLAY variable with the command `export DISPLAY=:0`.